# How to display plugin with javascript using markup of the theme?

Tags: plugin-development

I have developed custom menu plugin and need to display custom menu without plugin short-code.

How to display plugin with javascript using markup of the theme?

Comment: This is your third variation on this question. It will help a lot if you can describe what you're ultimately trying to achieve in much more detail.

Comment: trying to display custom breadcrumb after installed plugin and without below short-code.
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[custom_breadcrumb]'); ?>

Comment: There's no 100% reliable way to identify a theme's navigation. It might not even be in a place where breadcrumbs would fit. There's a reason most (if not all) breadcrumb plugins require the user to use a widget or shortcode themselves, or to edit their theme. If you want to be future proof you might want to implement the breadcrumbs as a Block, so that it can be used in Full Site Editing in the block editor. I have no experience with that myself, though.